# Speeding up PDE solver: numba, Cython, f2py, or other?

Tags: python, cython, scientific-computing, f2py, numba

I've been writing a PDE finite element solver in Python using NumPy. It works great but it's getting to the stage where the run times are long. I want to optimize the code, I've used profilers, etc, but I think the next step is to optimize using numba, Cython, f2py, or other. I'm feeling overwhelmed, though, as different links seem to say that one is faster than the other. Can anyone provide solid advice on how to evaluate these options for speeding up my code?

Comment: As with all optimizations:  Benchmark and compare

Comment: I'm worried about that approach. Is there really no better way than to become an expert in three different optimization methods and to re-write my code 3 times?

Comment: It looks like numba should be able to compile regular python code.  That sounds like a good place to start.  Does that give you the performance that you want/need?

Comment: changing languages usually at best gives 100% speedup (half the time) see if you can decrease the growth of your algorithm

Comment: Lorna Barbara has examples for PDE solver with numba

Comment: @PatrickRinker did you look at PyClaw, FEniCS, FiPy, sfepy, firedrake, petsc4py, PyTrilinos?

Comment: Actually, it depends on your approach. Having worked with `cython` and `f2py`, both will give you speed increase. One one side, after profiling your code, you can start rewriting only the crucial part in either C or Fortran and finally wrap it and compile it with `f2py`. On the other side, with `cython` you will need to modify your original Python code in a sort of dialect mixture of C and Python. Then you will generate C code, which is not trivial to read (similar to machine code). As you can see it depends on the approach you want to give.

Comment: Did you have a look at nuitka? It works like a charm